# How to list all configuration files for an already installed package?

Tags: package-management, configuration

I am running Ubuntu 12.10 and, if possible, I would like to get the list of configuration files available for a given package that is already installed.

I would prefer to do this using dpkg or apt if possible, but no problem if other tools such as aptitude or dselect are needed/recommended.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

There's no need to use anything other than `cat`, if I understood your intention correctly:

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/<package>.conffiles
```

should give you what you're after. For instance for package zsh:

```
% cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/zsh.conffiles
/etc/zsh/zlogin
/etc/zsh/zlogout
/etc/zsh/zprofile
/etc/zsh/zshenv
/etc/zsh/zshrc
/etc/zsh/newuser.zshrc.recommended
```

Regarding a case where there's no such file for a given package - it's up to the package maintainer to designate certain files as configuration. If this hasn't been done properly, you should file a bug where appropriate.

In such cases you have a couple of options.

1. List files belonging to the package that are in /etc/:

   ```
   dpkg -L package | grep '/etc'
   ```
2. Fetch and inspect the source package to find out how it was compiled (which should also show you where it expects its configuration files to be located).

   ```
   apt-get source package
   less package-x.y.z/debian/rules
   ```
3. Look up the upstream project page to find documentation.

Comment: If a given package is not having such a file .conffiles under this path, does it mean it is no using configuration files?

Comment: Not necessarily - it might be that there are indeed configuration files used by the package but the packager did not designate any files as part of the packaged application's configuration files.

Comment: The .conffiles file will list all configuration files that *ship with* the package and are marked as such by the packager. An automatically-installed one that does not appear there is a packaging bug, but be aware that some files (particularly user-specific configuration in a user's dotfiles) cannot ship with the package and can't really be automatically located unless you already know what they are.

Answer (score 2):

Let's for example test the package `apt` to get the config file(s).

It can be tricky to understand what `.conffiles` you should check to see the info so I suggest using `grep` to find the clue.

```
locate *.conffiles | grep apt

/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt-config-icons.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apt.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/aptdaemon.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/apturl-common.conffiles
/var/lib/dpkg/info/libatk-adaptor:amd64.conffiles
```

And to `cat` any of these in particular if you are interested according to Marcin's Kaminski answer.

Another trick is to read the manual, for instance `man apt` will lead you to SEE ALSO section from where you can call `man apt.conf` where you will see the location of the config file for `apt` in this case: `/etc/apt/apt.conf`.

However, config file `/etc/apt/apt.conf` may not even exist. Be aware of that when searching for the config files.

In Linux config files should be inside the `/etc/` directory. You may use `dpkg-query -L your_package | grep etc` to list all package files and directories inside the `/etc/` directory.

Answer (score 1):

How about dpkg -S [package-name]? Cant see it being mentioned here.

```
root@homehub:/# dpkg -S nginx

nginx-common: /usr/share/nginx/html
nginx-full: /usr/share/man/man8/nginx.8.gz
libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter/copyright
nginx-common: /etc/logrotate.d/nginx
libnginx-mod-mail: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-mail/changelog.gz
libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair
libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam/changelog.Debian.gz
libnginx-mod-http-image-filter: /usr/lib/nginx/modules/ngx_http_image_filter_module.so
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/snippets
libnginx-mod-mail: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-mail/copyright
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf
libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter/changelog.Debian.gz
nginx-full: /usr/share/doc/nginx-full/copyright
nginx-common: /usr/share/doc/nginx-common
nginx-common: /etc/ufw/applications.d/nginx
libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair/changelog.gz
libnginx-mod-stream: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-stream.conf
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/sites-enabled
libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair/copyright
libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter/changelog.gz
libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-dav-ext.conf
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/koi-utf
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/mime.types
nginx-common: /usr/share/vim/addons/syntax/nginx.vim
nginx-common: /usr/share/doc/nginx-common/NEWS.Debian.gz
nginx-common: /usr/share/doc/nginx-common/README.Debian
nginx-full: /usr/share/doc/nginx-full
libnginx-mod-mail: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-mail.conf
libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam/changelog.gz
nginx: /usr/share/doc/nginx
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/win-utf
libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext: /usr/share/doc/libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext
....
```

And sometimes depending on filename structure it might be good if piped out to grep names containing ".conf":

```
root@homehub:/# dpkg -S nginx |grep ".conf"

nginx-common: /etc/nginx/snippets/fastcgi-php.conf
libnginx-mod-stream: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-stream.conf
libnginx-mod-http-dav-ext: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-dav-ext.conf
libnginx-mod-mail: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-mail.conf
libnginx-mod-http-auth-pam: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-auth-pam.conf
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/fastcgi.conf
nginx-common: /etc/init/nginx.conf
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/conf.d
libnginx-mod-http-subs-filter: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-subs-filter.conf
libnginx-mod-http-geoip: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-geoip.conf
libnginx-mod-http-echo: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-echo.conf
libnginx-mod-http-upstream-fair: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-upstream-fair.conf
nginx-common: /etc/init/nginx.conf
libnginx-mod-http-xslt-filter: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-xslt-filter.conf
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/snippets/snakeoil.conf
nginx-common: /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
libnginx-mod-http-image-filter: /usr/share/nginx/modules-available/mod-http-image-filter.conf
```