# How to list configuration files for a package before installing the package?

Tags: apt, package-management, dpkg

I learned how to view the configuration files for a package that's already installed from reading:

[How to list all configuration files for an already installed package?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/281853/how-to-list-all-configuration-files-for-an-already-installed-package)

Using dnsmasq as an example, I can view the files and configuration files for that package after it's installed using these two commands:

```
cat /var/lib/dpkg/info/dnsmasq.conffiles
dpkg -L dnsmasq
```

I know I can search for the existence of the package and get relevant meta data about the package using these commands

```
dpkg --list | grep dnsmasq
apt-cache search dnsmasq
apt-cache show dnsmasq
```

But, I'd like to know the configuration files for the package before installing it.

How do I list configuration files for a package before installing the package?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can view the file list online on [packages.ubuntu.com](https://packages.ubuntu.com).

For example, for package `dnsmasq`, release `xenial` (16.04), architecture `all`, the URL is [packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/dnsmasq/filelist](https://packages.ubuntu.com/xenial/all/dnsmasq/filelist). Info copied here:

> ## File list of package *dnsmasq* in *xenial* of architecture *all*
>
> ```
> /etc/default/dnsmasq
> /etc/dnsmasq.conf
> /etc/dnsmasq.d/README
> /etc/init.d/dnsmasq
> /etc/insserv.conf.d/dnsmasq
> /etc/resolvconf/update.d/dnsmasq
> /lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
> /usr/lib/resolvconf/dpkg-event.d/dnsmasq
> /usr/share/doc/dnsmasq
> ```

Answer (score 2):

To compliment the @wjandrea [answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/1113364/66509) - you can use `apt-file`:

```
sudo apt install apt-file
sudo apt-file update
apt-file list dnsmasq
```

On 16.04 LTS you will get:

> ```
> $ apt-file list dnsmasq
> dnsmasq: /etc/default/dnsmasq
> dnsmasq: /etc/dnsmasq.conf
> dnsmasq: /etc/dnsmasq.d/README
> dnsmasq: /etc/init.d/dnsmasq
> dnsmasq: /etc/insserv.conf.d/dnsmasq
> dnsmasq: /etc/resolvconf/update.d/dnsmasq
> dnsmasq: /lib/systemd/system/dnsmasq.service
> dnsmasq: /usr/lib/resolvconf/dpkg-event.d/dnsmasq
> dnsmasq: /usr/share/doc/dnsmasq
> ```