# cannot find /etc/proxychains.conf after installing proxychains

Tags: 20.04, proxy, etc

I downloaded **proxychains** on **ubuntu 20.04** recently using

```
sudo apt install proxychains
```

Now for configuring the proxy addresses, I **cannot find the /etc/proxychains.conf file**.

What to do now?
Any terminal command that can be of help??

Comment: could be a duplicate of https://askubuntu.com/questions/281853/how-to-list-all-configuration-files-for-an-already-installed-package

Answer (score 2):

First, make sure the `proxychains` files are indexed by the
locate command

```
sudo updatedb
```

Once `updatedb` completes, use the `locate` command to see the location of the `.conf` file.

```
locate proxychains
```

Finally, use the command to access the configuration

```
sudo nano /etc/proxychains.conf
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you running the command on root? It seems like the proxy chain command when run on the root, cannot locate the proxy config file. To anybody who is having this trouble, try running proxy chain command in Terminal Emulator.